# Default tables & defining different levels in textboxes in Powerpoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have some more questions regarding powerpoint masters, preferably I would like to solve them in VBA, but if you have a "click solution" that would be highly appreciated, too.

1) How can I define custom default tables, and I do not like any of the Powerpoint 2010 suggestions, I would like to define my own default table. I know it is easy to use one of the given ones as default style, but I don't know how to get my layout into the choosable ones.

2) How can I set the indents and the bullets for the different levels in a textframe? I know how to set them for the whole placeholder, but not how to access level 2 onwards...

Thanks a lot
seba

Edit: on 2) I found out how to set the indents via Levels(), but the bullets seem to work via Paragraphs() which doesn't help when creating a master

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You can't define custom tables, or at least there's no UI or object model for it.  You could copy a pre-made table in from another slide in a presentation or template and paste it onto an existing slide as needed or start by adding the closest available pre-made table then your code could modify it to suit.

2) Work with the shape's .TextFrame.Ruler object to modify the .TabStops and .Levels collections.  .Levels(x).FirstMargin and .Levels(x).LeftMargin let you get/set the bullet indents.

X can take on values of 1 to 9 in PPT 2007 and up, 1 to 5 in earlier versions.

Comment: thanks, do you know how I can define the bullets so Level1-Level2-Level3-Level1 will give the same bullets for both level1? If I do it via paragraps() I need to have content in the boxes and it doesn't seem to work in the template

Comment: I don't quite understand the question, but in case it helps, you need to put text into the text box at each level before formatting it in order for the formatting to stick.  Dumb bug I suppose.  Try inserting some text at each level (something easily recognizable as "dummy" text, like !@#$#@!.  Format it then remove any text matching that dummy string.